# weird issue with strtotime function (PHP) - how to fix?

Tags: php

I'm having weird issues with strtotime function in PHP.

This is my code:

```
$firstregdate = null;
if (! is_null($item["refer_date"])) {
    $temp = explode("/", $item["refer_date"]);
    $firstregdate = date("d/m/y", mktime(0, 0, 0, $temp[1], $temp[0], $temp[2]));
}
$epsstartdate = null;
if (! is_null($item["start_date"])) {
    $temp = explode("/", $item["start_date"]);
    $epsstartdate = date("d/m/y", mktime(0, 0, 0, $temp[1], $temp[0], $temp[2]));
}
$epsclosedate = null;
if (! is_null($item["end_date"])) {
    $temp = explode("/", $item["end_date"]);
    $epsclosedate = date("d/m/y", mktime(0, 0, 0, $temp[1], $temp[0], $temp[2]));
}

echo $firstregdate." | ".$epsstartdate." | ".$epsclosedate."<br>";
echo strtotime($firstregdate)." | ".strtotime($epsstartdate)." | ".strtotime($epsclosedate)."<br>";
```

This is the output:

```
08/02/13 | 13/02/13 | 05/03/14
1375367400 | | 1399041000
```

As you can see, strtotime($epsstartdate) didn't give me any value. But looking at the value, it is a date datatype and it seems to be in the correct format.

Any ideas? thanks

Comment: Why not try doing this stuff with a single function, I reckon you are doing too much duplication in your code...

Comment: Dates are in the format `mm/dd/yy`. There is no month 13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strtotime` expects dates to be in the format `mm/dd/yy` if you use the `/` delimiter. You can fix this by changing your calls to `date()`:

```
$epsstartdate = date("m/d/y", mktime(0, 0, 0, $temp[1], $temp[0], $temp[2]));
```

Or you could use `DateTime::createFromFormat()` to parse the date in the format you have:

```
echo DateTime::parseFromFormat('d/m/y', $firstregdate)." | ".DateTime::parseFromFormat('d/m/y', $epsstartdate)." | ".DateTime::parseFromFormat('d/m/y', $epsclosedate)."<br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You may declare a function to deal with customized date format

```
function format_date($str,$format,$convertTo){
    switch($format){
        case "d/m/y":
            list($d,$m,$y) =  explode("/",$str);
            break;
        case "m/d/y":
            list($m,$d,$y) =  explode("/",$str);
            break;
        //You can customize your own format here
    }

    $timestamp = ($format) ? strtotime("$y-$m-$d") : strtotime($str);

    return date($convertTo,$timestamp);
}

// Date is same but with different format
$date_a = "2014-02-01"; //  Y-m-d
$date_b = "01/02/2014"; //  d/m/y
$date_c = "02/01/2014"; //  m/d/y

$convertTo = "Y-m-d";
echo format_date($date_a,false,$convertTo);
echo "<br/>";
echo format_date($date_b,"d/m/y",$convertTo);
echo "<br/>";
echo format_date($date_c,"m/d/y",$convertTo);
```

Result:

```
2014-02-01
2014-02-01
2014-02-01
```

Answer (score 0):

[strtotime manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) says,

Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed.
To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD) dates or DateTime::createFromFormat() when possible.

In your case, date is considered as m/d/y format which makes strtotime returns false as the month is invalid.